# Dynamically allocating memory for changing array size starting with unknown size C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, allocation

How do I dynamically allocate an array where the size will be changing because the stuff stored in the array will be read from a file. There are lots of suggestions on using a vector, but I want to know how to do it the array way.

I know for memory allocation it is

```
int count;
int *n = new int[count];
```

Say the variable count is going to increment in a loop. How would I change the size of the array?

Also, what if we did it using malloc?

Comment: You will have to delete the vector n and create a new one bigger. And there is no point to use malloc if you can use new.

Comment: See the realloc example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/

Comment: @JaviV Except that malloc can support realloc whereas there is no equivilent for new.

Comment: why not using a [vector](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=c%2B%2B+vector)?

Comment: Do I have to initialize count to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to make the array allocation exactly follow the continual changing size requirements of what you are going to store. Consider using the traditional 2*N multiple. When array is full, reallocate by growing by 2*N (allocate a new array twice as large), and copy items over. This amortizes the reallocation cost logarithmically.

Keep in mind that this logic you are setting out to implement with low level arrays is exactly why vector exists. You are not likely to implement your own as efficiently, or as bug free.

But if you are set on it, keep count a multiple of 2, starting with something realistic (or the nearest multiple of 2 rounded up)

Comment: So does that mean I would have to make many arrays since I have to copy the items over?

Comment: Or can I copy to one array and then free the first array then reallocate again and copy into the old array and free the new array? So basically just use only two arrays?

Comment: Doenst do any good to hold on to the old one, the only time you reallocate is when you outgrow the array, so you always move up, not down. Once the array grows there isn't really any advantage in sizing back down, just leave it as it is.

Comment: No, after resize, once you copy the items to the new array, delete the old one.

Comment: And this is one particular use case where you are justified to use malloc/realloc for the array storage. Secondly, make sure to encapsulate all this in a class. The class should have the current size, and the array pointer.

Comment: Could you maybe give an example?

Answer (score 2):

You may keep two pointers, p and q(placeholder), when count changes, you need to do a fresh allocation for p, before that earlier allocations need to be deallocated, even before that the contents of earlier p should be transferred to new p as well.

```
int count, oldcount;
int *p = NULL;
int *q;
p = new int[count];
oldcount = count;
```

when you need to re-allocate:

```
q = new int[count];
memcpy(q, p, oldcount * sizeof(int)); // OR for (int i = 0; i < oldcount; i++) q[i] = p[i];   
delete [] p;
p = q;
oldcount = count; // for use later
```

If you use malloc, calloc then you need to use as number of bytes to pass in malloc. but not needed with new and delete operators in C++

Comment: @JaviV thanks, edited my ans, and also thanks to Wyzard

Answer (score 1):

> How would I change the size of the array?

Using `new`: You can't. The size of an object (here, an array object) can't change at runtime.

You would have to create a new array with the appropriate size, copy all elements from the old into the new array and destroy the old one. 
To avoid many reallocations you should always allocate more than you need. Keep track of the `size` (the amount of elements currently in use) and the `capacity` (the actual size of the allocated array). Once you want to increase the `size`, check whether there is still some memory left (`size<capacity`) and use that if possible; otherwise, apply the aforementioned method.

And that's **exactly** what `vector` does for you: But with RAII and all the convenience possible.

Comment: Actually realloc does not always move the memory block. If enough contiguous memory is available after the block to be reallocated then the block is not moved. If the block has to be moved realloc does the copy... So it is not always that one has to allocate new memory and  copy

Comment: @ds27680 We're not talking about `malloc/realloc`, but `new`.

Comment: He actually asked how to dynamically allocate an array whose size is bound to change. He gave new as an example (the way he knows allocation can be done).  Your answer as I read it would imply that you allways have to allocate new and copy. You did not mention that you are reffering only to new when you say: You can't.

Comment: He also asked at the end of his question. Also, what if we did it using malloc? So his question is obviously not only about new but also about malloc. While your answer gives the impression that what you say generally applies.

Comment: @ds27680 Oh, i didn't see the part about `malloc`.